# How to make a Runnable Change a given value

Tags: java, runnable

So the problem I am currently facing is that I want to write a method, that creates a runnable that changes a given Value; in this case it's a Boolean Object.

(I use this, to make it possible to react on different ways 
to a Key Press)

If I am just using a Method of the passed Object it works just fine.

However:

```
public static Runnable createOnOffSwitchRunnable(Boolean b)
{
    final Boolean Reference = b;
    Runnable R = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            if (Reference.booleanValue() == true)
            {
                Reference = false;
            }
        }
    };
    return R;
}
```

Obviously this does **not** work, as I can't directly assign a value to the final Variable and the Boolean Object has no "set"-method. However I NEED to declare it final to even be able to create the Runnable.

So is there no way how you can change a passed value, with a runnable? (it would be nice if I could keep on using standard java Types instead of "inventing" some new class)

If so, are there any alternatives for saving and passing methods?

Any help would be appreciated (:

Comment: You can't change immutable objects. That's WHY they're immutable.

Comment: BTW this code does not make too much sense... You'd only change the value of a local variable - that, by when the runnable starts to run is not even in scope anymore...

Comment: Please try a second to understand my problem. Of course I can't change a final value. That was not the question. 
The question was if there is no way to change a value with a runnable, and if so, if there was another way that works simmilar

Comment: You could pass a reference to the object holding the boolean, and change it directly. You could also make it public static, so that's it's accessible everywhere. There's lots of things you could do. The "right" one, depends heavily on the situation

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't public static imply that it is callable by every other class?
Also Boolean b is an object, so you can pass every object to it, not just a local one.

Comment: Also it IS public static.
And Boolean b IS a Reference, it is not a type like int, double or boolean (notice the capital B)

Comment: I feel like you didn't even read my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The local variable you call `Reference`  exists only while `createOnOffSwitchRunnable` is running and disappears when it returns; it makes no sense to modify it. You can modify an instance variable though, if it makes sense in your case. If you do this you should declare the variable `volatile` to prevent stale reads (also called ["the law of the blind spot"](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue150.html)).

```
volatile Boolean Reference;

public static Runnable createOnOffSwitchRunnable(Boolean b)
{
    Reference = b;

    Runnable R = new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            if (Reference.booleanValue() == true)
            {
                Reference = false;
            }
        }
    };
    return R;
}
```

Another option is making `Reference` an instance variable in the Runnable. This might also solve your problem, I have no idea what you're trying to do.

```
public static Runnable createOnOffSwitchRunnable(final Boolean b)
{

    Runnable R = new Runnable()
    {
        private Boolean Reference = b;

        public void run()
        {
            if (Reference.booleanValue() == true)
            {
                Reference = false;
            }
        }
    };
    return R;
}
```

(Also, please use standard naming conventions, written it title case `Reference` looks like the name of a class.)

Comment: Hey! That really worked. Thank you very much (:
To the temporary variable: It should be a Reference, so it shouldn't matter if I call b.x or Reference.x as "Reference" is definined as a... Reference to b.
Am I wrong?

Comment: @JonasBartkowski it does matter. it should be `reference`. Not `Reference`

Comment: I was not talking about the naming convention^^ I was talking about his thoughts about the variable "Reference" disappearing after the method stops running. In my opinion it does not matter, as "Reference" reffers to the passed Object b and should therefore be absolutely interchangeable with it.

Comment: Also are you a troll? Your comments have been false, unconstructive and unfriendly so far. I am flagging you.

Comment: Ah.. When you write `Reference = false` what you do is make the *variable* point to a new object. That makes sense only while the variable is in scope. The type of the variable doesn't make any difference: it's the same for `int` as for reference types.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this trick, which is as close as you'll get to your intention:

```
public static Runnable createOnOffSwitchRunnable(final Boolean... b) {
    return new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (b[0].booleanValue()) {
                b[0] = false;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

I've done the following:

- made the parameter final, instead if creating a separate final local variable
- made the parameter varags, which is actually an array inside the method, but which the caller can call with a single Boolean parameter so effectively the signature looks the same for this case
- the parameter *array* is final, but its *contents* are not - this is the "trick"
- simplified the logic:: testing `booleanValue==true` is an anti-pattern, just test booleanValue itself
- return the Runnable without creating a (needless) local variable

Comment: Thank you for this solution! I think it is very helpful as well, because it does not need an external volatile variable like Joni's solution.

However, wouldn't that solution make it impossible to pass a non-final variable? (I was trying to avoid that by the seemingly unnessecary redifinition)

Comment: Note I accidentally left off the `[]` from the parameter, so there's that change to the signature. The point is that you pass in a final *array*, so the *reference* is final, but you can change its *contents* - it's a work around to the problem of only being allowed to have access to final variables,  but needing to assign a value to it.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `AtomicBoolean`. It will have the advantage of being thread-safe.